# Spring MVC, two buttons work with one form, how they work together?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

[image]

What I am doing here is when I enter a bookname in textbook and click edit button. The textboxes below will show this book's all information. Then I can edit information in the same textboxes. In the end, I click update and the new information will be updated.I have edit part done, I can edit all information by given certain bookname. Now I am confused how to do update part, because both edit and update will use the same form(those textboxes), then how to handle post or get request? Someone can explain to me? Thank you.

controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEditBookForm(@ModelAttribute("editBook") Book editBook, HttpServletRequest request) {

        return "editbook";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView processEditBookForm(@ModelAttribute("editBook") Book editBook ){

    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("editbook");
    mv.addObject("resulteditBook",bookService.getBookByName(editBook.getBookName()) );
    return mv;
}
```

jsp:

```
<form:form modelAttribute="editBook" >

        <div>Enter BOOK NAME: <input type="text" name=bookName
                style="width: 100">

            <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit">
    </div>
    </form:form>

<form:form modelAttribute="updateBook" >
    ......
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" name="update">
    </p>
    </form:form>
```

Comment: You can use two separated forms for each request method, or change form method to "GET" or "POST" before every submit

Answer (score 1):

You can have something like

```
<input type="submit" class="button" name="edit" value="edit"/>
<input type="submit" class="button" name="update" value="update"/>
```

and distinguish your conroller methods based on the param e.g. for edit

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "edit")
public String edit() {
...  
}
```

and for update

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method = RequestMethod.POST, params = "update")
public String update() {
...  
}
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. But I tried this one, it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value = "/update", params = "update", method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String processUpdateBookForm( @ModelAttribute("updateBook") Book updateBook, HttpServletRequest request) {

  bookService.updateBook(updateBook);

  return "books";
 }`

Answer (score 0):

Try This way

jsp

```
<form:form commandName="editBook" method="post" action="edit.do" id="editForm" >

        <div>Enter BOOK NAME: <input type="text" name=bookName
                style="width: 100">

            <input type="submit" value="Edit" name="edit"   onClick="editFormsubmit();">">
    </div>
    </form:form>

<form:form commandName="updateBook" method="post" action="update.do" id="updateForm"  >
    ......
    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Update" name="update" onClick="updateFormsubmit();">
    </p>
    </form:form>
```

javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
function updateFormsubmit() {
     document.getElementById("updateForm").submit(); 
}

function editFormsubmit() {
     document.getElementById("editForm").submit(); 
}
</script>
```

Controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/edit", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String getEditBookForm(@ModelAttribute("editBook") Book editBook, HttpServletRequest request) {

        return "editbook";
    }

@RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView processEditBookForm(@ModelAttribute("updateBook") Book editBook ){
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("editbook");
    mv.addObject("resulteditBook",bookService.getBookByName(editBook.getBookName()) );
    return mv;
}
```